# Concatenating string with number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

I'm trying to create a simple calculator in Javascript. I have an array named expression
    `chunk[0] = 12`
    `chunk[1] = +` (the "+" sign)
    `chunk[1] = 5`

I used a for loop to loop through the chunks (chunk[]) and join then into a single expression as follows:-

```
equation = ""; // To make var equation a string

for(i = 0; i <= length; i++)
{
    equation = equation + expression[i];
    alert(expression[i]);
}

alert(equation);
```

`alert(expression[i])` showed values 12, + and 5.
But alert(equation) showed 125 (instead of "12+5"). I need the variable equation to be "12+5" so that I can later call eval(equation) and get the value of 12+5.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you get syntax error for writing `chunk[1] = +`?

Comment: made a quick test at http://jsfiddle.net/7y4Ha/ - everything works fine. Have you tried `equation = equation + expression[i].toString();` to prevent a wrong typecast? if my presets are wrong please correct me.

Comment: @Nikita I was just showing what their contents were. It wasn't assignment I meant :-) sry if it confused u.

Comment: @Samuel Herzog The fiddle corrects the typo in the original question, so `chunk[1]` is no longer `'+'` then over-written to `5`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have `chunk = [ 12, '+', 5];` then you can do `var eq = chunk.join("");` and then pass it to eval

Comment: Using `eval` carelessly is not a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing wrong?  You have a small typo.

Amend the code on the question from

```
chunk[0] = 12
chunk[1] = '+'
chunk[1] = 5
```

to

```
chunk[0] = 12
chunk[1] = '+'
chunk[2] = 5
```

And everything should work.

**Why this works:**
Both the `+` and the `5` are being assigned to `chunk[1]`, with the `5` over-writing the previous assignment ( to `chunk[1]`) of `+`.  This also explains why the concatenated value displayed is `125`

In order, the first assignment results in a collection with
a member `chunk[0]` and a content of `12`

The second assignment adds a new member, and results in a collection with
a member `chunk[0]` whose content is `12`
a member `chunk[1]` whose content is `+`

The third assignment overwrites the 2nd member, and results in a collection with
a member `chunk[0]` whose content is `12`
a member `chunk[1]` whose content is `5`

The concatenation of all the chunks == `125`

Desired concatenation == `12+5`

Comment: In the original question, both the '' and the '5' were assigned to chunk[1]

I think the author intended to assign the '+' to chunk[1] and the '5' to chunk[2].  

As stated in the original question, he assigned both values to chunk[1], and therefore overwrote the value '+' with the value '5'.

This also explains the observed behaviour.